# Making sense of setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get a series of sentences to appear 2 seconds after the previous one, using setTimeout to display each sentence, and setInterval to repeat this process for a set number of times (as defined by the user).

The following sample code shows where I am in my understanding, and where I am confused:

```js
 var myComments = document.getElementById("comments");
 var subtractor = 5;
 var timer, myRun;
 
 window.onload = onStart();
 
 function onStart() {
  alert("First Comment");
  myRun = setInterval(function() {
   alert("Sub = " + subtractor);
   setTimer("<p>This is a first sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>");
   setTimer("<p>This is a second sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>");
   setTimer("<p>This is a third sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>");
   subtractor = subtractor - 1;
   if (subtractor < 1) {
    alert("Subtractor to clear");
    clearInterval(myRun);
    }
  }, 2000);
  alert("Last Comment");
 }
 
 function setTimer(setText) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {myComments.innerHTML = myComments.innerHTML + setText;}, 2000);
 }
```

```html
<div id="comments"></div>
```

The alerts are simply there as test points, and show my lack of understanding:

- Why is the last alert shown immediately after the first one, and THEN the alerts from within the setInterval? - Because the setTimeout is asynchronous!
- Why are none of the sentences displayed at all, aside from the very last sentence generated? - Since they are asynchronous, the next timer cancels the previous one, leaving only the last one to be displayed.
- Where am I going wrong? How DO I get sentences to appear one after the other, with a two second delay between each one? Do I nest each timer in the previous?

Sorry, that last question is more in my own head; off to test!

Comment: setTimeout/setInterval are **asyncrhonous** - all your setTimer calls are done one after the other without waiting for the timeout to expire - therefore only the last will actually run, because each call to setTimer stops the previous setTimeout

Comment: I understood they ran asynchronously, hence the last alert running prior to the setInterval one. Your comment makes that "oh yes!" moment, where it becomes clearer why the text is not appearing (thanks for that).
So, given this, how DO I get the text to run one after the other, two seconds apart?

Comment: ahh, the real question, how do I do what I want to do. You'd use the simple but error prone way of increasing timeouts, or use callbacks to call the next part when the current part finishes ... or, simplify the callback chain by using Promises (which are a simple way to chain callbacks) or the now popular async/await

Comment: Is that always the ultimate question? Yet I don't simply want the answer; no fun in that. I want to understand why, so that I never need to ask this question again! With yours and Daniel's response I am a lot closer. No, I understand now (aside from your Promises and callback references; I have further research to do later), and need to think if I have finally gained sufficient knowledge to put this problem to bed.

Comment: Sure, that may be the ultimate question, but sometimes the knowledge of what you've done wrong is enough - not always, but I'm not going to give an answer without first letting you try to figure it out once you've had the "oh yes" or "lightbulb" moment :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the last alert shown immediately after the first one, and THEN the alerts from within the setInterval?

The last alert isn't inside a setTimeout or setInterval, so fires immediately. The others are inside a 2000ms setTimeout, so fire two seconds later (all at once).

> Why are none of the sentences displayed at all, aside from the very last sentence generated?

You're firing three simultaneous setTimeouts with the same 2000ms delay, so   all three of them fire almost simultaneously two seconds later.  The clearTimeouts inside them are colliding with each other (because you reuse the same `timer` variable to keep track of them all) which is preventing two of them from ever firing.

> Where am I going wrong?

Each of your calls to setTimer should use a different time delay so they don't fire all at once.  The setInterval, meanwhile, should have a long enough interval so it doesn't loop before the three setTimeouts it sets up are complete.  There is no need to call clearTimeout on the setTimout calls; by default they'll run once and then stop, which is what you want.  The only place you need that is to stop the setInterval.

You may also want to trigger the first iteration immediately, so it'll start right away instead of waiting for the first interval to complete:

```js
var myComments = document.getElementById("comments");
var subtractor = 5;
var timer, myRun;

window.onload = onStart();

function setTimers() {
  //alert("Sub = " + subtractor);
  setTimer("<p>This is a first sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>", 0); // no delay
  setTimer("<p>This is a second sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>", 2000); // 2s delay
  setTimer("<p>This is a third sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>", 4000); // 4s delay
  subtractor = subtractor - 1;
  if (subtractor < 1) {
    //alert("Subtractor to clear");
    clearInterval(myRun);
  }
}

function onStart() {
  //alert("First Comment");
  myRun = setInterval(setTimers, 6000); // 6 seconds for the full interval
  setTimers(); // so you don't have to wait 6 seconds for the first run
}

function setTimer(setText, delay) {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    myComments.innerHTML = myComments.innerHTML + setText;
  }, delay);
}
```

```html
<div id="comments"></div>
```

Comment: Just one thing to clarify - you're only seeing the last sentence because you were ending the timer with the `clearTimeout` call before it could fire.  Not really an issue, as Daniel pointed out you don't need the clearTimeout there anyway (in fact it doesn't looks like you even need to assign the `setTimeout` result to a variable - it's mostly only useful if you're going to cancel it).

Comment: (Yes, thanks for pointing that out, @MikeB. -- I had the wrong explanation for that  part first time round, have edited the answer to correct it)

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Since the number of repetitions depends upon the value entered by the user, I will test in a moment, but am assuming that once the setInterval refires after 6000, I allow the setTimeout intervals to begin at 0 again?

Comment: Yep, exactly right.  The first iteration sets up timeouts at 0, 2, and 4 seconds from the start. The second iteration happens at 6 seconds,  and sets up timeouts at 0, 2, and 4 seconds from that point in time (so 6, 8, and 10 seconds after the start); then the third iteration happens 6 seconds later (at 12 seconds from start), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the other answer explains the problem, I'll just answer the "how I would achieve what I want" comment - starting with the most modern (and cleanest code) way

```js
var myComments = document.getElementById("comments");
var delay = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
var subtractor = 5;

window.onload = onStart();

async function onStart() {
    for (let i = subtractor; i > 0; --i) {
        await setTimer("<p>This is a first sentence. Subtractor = " + i + "</p>");
        await setTimer("<p>This is a second sentence. Subtractor = " + i + "</p>");
        await setTimer("<p>This is a third sentence. Subtractor = " + i + "</p>");
    }
}

async function setTimer(setText) {
    await delay(2000);
    myComments.innerHTML = myComments.innerHTML + setText;
}
```

```html
<div id="comments"></div>
```

---

Now the promise chaining which basically just simplifies callback pyramids

```js
var myComments = document.getElementById("comments");
var delay = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
var subtractor = 5;

window.onload = onStart();

function onStart() {
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i = subtractor; i > 0; --i) {
        p = p.then (() => setTimer("<p>This is a first sentence. Subtractor = " + i + "</p>"));
        p = p.then (() => setTimer("<p>This is a second sentence. Subtractor = " + i + "</p>"));
        p = p.then (() => setTimer("<p>This is a third sentence. Subtractor = " + i + "</p>"));
    }
}

function setTimer(setText) {
    return delay(2000).then(() => {
        myComments.innerHTML = myComments.innerHTML + setText;
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="comments"></div>
```

---

And now, the old school callback chaining - you can see the pyramid of doom forming in this one!

```js
var myComments = document.getElementById("comments");
var subtractor = 5;

window.onload = onStart();

function onStart() {
    setTimer("<p>This is a first sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>", function() {;
        setTimer("<p>This is a second sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>", function() {
            setTimer("<p>This is a third sentence. Subtractor = " + subtractor + "</p>", function() {
                subtractor = subtractor - 1;
                if (subtractor > 0) {
                    onStart();
                }
            })
        });
    });
}

function setTimer(setText, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myComments.innerHTML = myComments.innerHTML + setText;
        cb();
    }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div id="comments"></div>
```

---

I won't bother with the most simplistic way of doing what you want with "ever increasing timeout values", as that has been shown already

Comment: I believe comments should not be used for "thank you" statements, but I am incredibly grateful nonetheless; I have spent two days, on and off, trying to get my head around this, and have had the eureka moment when testing Daniel's response; it becomes completely clear and so damn obvious. I had already strayed in to the pyramid method; but aborted due to the ugly nature of the solution. The others are outside my current understanding at present, and would require lengthier discussions. Something for another day maybe. So, against the rules; thank you.

Comment: @Gazzieh - that's perfectly fine - once you get your head around Promises and async/await, you'll wonder how you managed without them :p